# How does the ISRI Stemmer give better stem words than Lancaster or Snowball Stemmer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have this sample text which i want to tokenize and subsequently find the stem words

```
sample_text = "'I am a student from the University of Alabama. \
I was born in Ontario, Canada and I am a huge fan of the United States. \
I am going to get a degree in Philosophy to improve\
my chances of becoming a Philosophy professor. \
I have been working towards this goal for 4 years. \
I am currently enrolled in a PhD program. \
It is very difficult, but I am confident that it will be a good decision'"
```

Using Lancaster Stemmer I am getting the following result -

```
sentences = sent_tokenize(sample_text)

from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer

lancaster = LancasterStemmer()

for i in range(len(sentences)):
    
    sentences[i] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', sentences[i])
    
    sentences[i] = word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    
    stopwds = [word.lower() for word in stopwords.words('english')]
    
    sentences[i] = [word.lower() for word in sentences[i] if word.lower() not in stopwds]
    
    sentences[i] = [lancaster.stem(word) for word in sentences[i]]
    
    print(sentences[i])
```

Output of Lancaster Stemmer:

```
['stud', 'univers', 'alabam']
['born', 'ontario', 'canad', 'hug', 'fan', 'unit', 'stat']
['going', 'get', 'degr', 'philosoph', 'improvemy', 'chant', 'becom', 'philosoph', 'profess']
['work', 'toward', 'goal', '4', 'year']
['cur', 'enrol', 'phd', 'program']
['difficult', 'confid', 'good', 'decid']
```

Output with Snowball stemmer -

```
['student', 'univers', 'alabama']
['born', 'ontario', 'canada', 'huge', 'fan', 'unit', 'state']
['go', 'get', 'degre', 'philosophi', 'improvemi', 'chanc', 'becom', 'philosophi', 'professor']
['work', 'toward', 'goal', '4', 'year']
['current', 'enrol', 'phd', 'program']
['difficult', 'confid', 'good', 'decis']
```

Output of Porter Stemmer

```
['student', 'univers', 'alabama']
['born', 'ontario', 'canada', 'huge', 'fan', 'unit', 'state']
['go', 'get', 'degre', 'philosophi', 'improvemi', 'chanc', 'becom', 'philosophi', 'professor']
['work', 'toward', 'goal', '4', 'year']
['current', 'enrol', 'phd', 'program']
['difficult', 'confid', 'good', 'decis']
```

Whereas ISRI Stemmer almost gives me same results as if the words had been lemmatized

```
sentences = sent_tokenize(sample_text)
from nltk.stem import ISRIStemmer
isri = ISRIStemmer()
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    
    sentences[i] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', sentences[i])
    
    sentences[i] = word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    
    stopwds = [word.lower() for word in stopwords.words()]
    
    sentences[i] = [word.lower() for word in sentences[i] if word.lower() not in stopwds]
    
    sentences[i] = [ isri.stem(word) for word in sentences[i]]
    
    print(sentences[i])
```

Output :

```
['student', 'university', 'alabama']
['born', 'ontario', 'canada', 'huge', 'fan', 'united', 'states']
['going', 'get', 'degree', 'philosophy', 'improvemy', 'chances', 'becoming', 'philosophy', 'professor']
['working', 'towards', 'goal', '4', 'years']
['currently', 'enrolled', 'phd', 'program']
['difficult', 'confident', 'good', 'decision']
```

Can someone explain how ISRI Stemmer gives almost Lemmatized words

Answer (score 0):

This stemmer was developed specifically for Arabic, that is why you are getting such results when using it on English.
Here is a link to the nltk doc https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/isri.html

Comment: is it better to use ISRI than either snowball or porter or even wordnetlemmatizer always

Comment: Since you are working with English you need an English-specific stemmer. Snowball is considered an improved version of Porter stemmer. So, I would recommend going with Snowball. Lancaster allows you to add your own stemming rules, but those can be tricky